# Error in ogrInfo (dsn =dsn,

Tags: r

Colegas.

Al leer otro archivo que está en la misma carpeta del entorno de trabajo me aparece:

```
source("Functions.R")
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open data source
```

Cambié de computador y ahora no lee las funciones

Comment: Hola Semillaca, bienvenido/a  te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y veas [ask] así también como crear un [mcve]. Tu pregunta así como está, es bastante pobre como para que podamos ayudarte, te sugiero que la edites y agregues toda información que sea relevante, como el  código que genera el error, una descripción de lo que hace y cualquier dato que nos ayude a darte un diagnóstico. Saludos.

Comment: @Semillaca esto no es forocoches, tal como dice Patricio Moracho , lee el recorrido y como preguntar, los estándares son muy importantes en stackoverflow, mantener la calidad de las preguntas es importante. Sobre el código entiende que nosotros no tenemos el contexto exacto de tu pregunta, así que cuanto mas lo desarrolles mejor, eso si, sin pegar 2000 lineas de código.

Answer (score 1):

Me he dado cuenta que las funciones de `rgdal` funcionan de manera diferente en sistemas operativos diferentes. Revisa como está definido `dsn` en el script y quizás ahí puede estar el problema.

Te puedo contar mi experiencia trabajando tanto en OS X como en Windows. Para leer un shapefile se ejecuta como genérico:

```r
library(rgdal)

readOGR(dsn,layer)
```

En OS X ninguna de las siguientes opciones levanta un error:

```r
readOGR(dsn='/ruta/a/carpeta/',layer='prueba')
readOGR(dsn='/ruta/a/carpeta',layer='prueba')
```

En Windows, la segunda me funciona sin problemas, pero la primera arroja el siguiente error:

```r
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open layer
```

Así que si la carpeta de trabajo contiene un `/` al final, puede ser que eso esté generando error en tu caso.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado Semillaca, me parece que esta es la solución:

```
  ######################################
  #             Server
  ######################################

  #Le digo al R donde debe jalar la data

  dirmapas <- "E:/Tu-carpeta/Tu-sub-carpeta/ESRI" #Depende donde tengas tú tus 
                                                  #archivos de cartografía 

  setwd(dirmapas)


  # El mapa de polígonos en blanco y negro
  departamentos<-readOGR(dsn="BAS_LIM_DEPARTAMENTO.shp", layer="BAS_LIM_DEPARTAMENTO")
```